# Aggregate group multiple fields and calculate average mondodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, pipeline

I have sample data like

```
db.student.insert({"name":"Vikash", "sub":"Physics", "marks":10})
db.student.insert({"name":"Vikash", "sub":"Math", "marks":20})
db.student.insert({"name":"Raj", "sub":"Physics", "marks":5})
db.student.insert({"name":"Raj", "sub":"Math", "marks":20})
db.student.insert({"name":"Vikash", "sub":"Physics", "marks":20})
db.student.insert({"name":"Vikash", "sub":"Math", "marks":30})
db.student.insert({"name":"Raj", "sub":"Physics", "marks":40})
db.student.insert({"name":"Raj", "sub":"Math", "marks":10})
```

And Sample output is:

```
    {
_id:"Vikash":[{
"sub":"Physics",
"avgMarks":15
},
{
"sub":"Math",
"avgMarks":25
}]
}

{
_id:"Raj":[{
"sub":"Physics",
"avgMarks":22.5
},
{
"sub":"Math",
"avgMarks":15
}]
}
```

Comment: can you correct your expected result, it is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Answer (score 1):

- `$group` by `name` and `sub` and get average `marks` by `$avg`
- `$group` by the only `name` and construct the subject array
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value array of object to an object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        sub: "$sub"
      },
      avgMarks: { $avg: "$marks" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.name",
      sub: {
        $push: {
          sub: "$_id.sub",
          avgMarks: "$avgMarks"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [{ k: "$_id", v: "$sub" }]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tr-RzLk3-DB)